# windows service fails to start while using a process to execute an exe file through c#.net

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am using a windows service to execute `ffmpeg.exe` for converting video files. I do this by staring a **process in c#.net**. The problem is that

My code within the OnStart() of windows service is as follows:

```
FilArgs = string.Format("-i {0} -ar 22050 -qscale 1 {1}", InputFile, OutputFile);

Process proc;
proc = new Process();

try
{
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = spath + "\\ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = FilArgs;
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

    eventLog1.WriteEntry("Going to start process of convertion");

    proc.Start();

    string StdOutVideo = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string StdErrVideo = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

    eventLog1.WriteEntry("Convertion Successful");
    eventLog1.WriteEntry(StdErrVideo);               

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    eventLog1.WriteEntry("Convertion Failed");
    eventLog1.WriteEntry(ex.ToString());            
}
finally
{
    proc.WaitForExit();
    proc.Close();
}
```

when i tried to convert large video files (i experienced it when the file size is >14MB) as mentioned above the service fails to start and is in the status "starting".

The ffmpeg while running directly through command prompt works fine for larger files as well.

Any one please me how to solve this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is bad because `onstart()` should only start a background thread for the worker loop. `OnStart()` should return pretty much immediately so no time consuming work must be done in there.

Windows waits for OnStart() to return within a timeout and if it does not, will kill it.

Basically you start a thread in there:

```
private Thread _workerThread;
private bool _closing = false;
... OnStart(...)
{
     _workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Work));
     _workerThread .Start();

}

private void Work()
{
    while(!_closing)
    {
    // do the processing if there is work otherwise sleep for say 10 seconds 
    }
}


... OnStop(...)
{
    _closing = true;
    _workerThread.Abort()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. But still i've got problems with time consuming file operations. After executing the function through thread as you mentioned, now the service is starting as normal. But the problem is my function is not completing. When i checked my eventlog it showed the log i did just before proc.Start();  (ie,"Going to start process of conversion").How can i get rid of this problem?

Comment: The problem with service is now solved and the original question is answered. Now you seem to have another problem with processing the data so I suggest youcreate a new question without the service stuff. I dont suggest updating this same question since it will pollute it.